# Why is my ajax request form_with being prevented by another rails form on page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using the form_with tag in my new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_with(url: "/instr_quizzes/new", method: 'post')  do %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:chart, "basic_expressions_quiz") %>
        <%= label_tag(:chart_basic_expressions_quiz , "View Basic Expressions Quiz") %><br>
        <%= submit_tag("View Quiz", :class=>"btn btn-warning", :name=>"submit") %>
    <% end %>
```

I have the respond_to in my controller.

```
    def new
       @instr_quiz = InstrQuiz.new
       @quizfile = params[:chart]
       respond_to do |f|
         f.html { }
         f.js 
       end
    end
```

I have the new.js.erb file to update the div.

```
    $('#quiz').html("<%= j render @quizfile %>")
```

From the logs you can see the problem: Why is it processing as HTML and not JS -- I used this same setup in a rail 5.0.6 app and it works. Is it in my application.js something with turbo links or rails-us??

```
Started POST "/instr_quizzes/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-15 05:55:33 -0500
Processing by InstrQuizzesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VKWmPvtwFrI6bYlQSFPaG8XiRKwvsIS83UGY9xoCyOAjKf5vRztamqfSTCfbUrVj0SDuAAs7FP+Gm14j2APEBA==", "chart"=>"basic_expressions_quiz", "submit"=>"View Quiz"}
Rendering instr_quizzes/new.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Application.js below

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```

Comment: Did you inspect the form in the browser? Does it have `data-remote="true"`?

Comment: There is no ajax behavior for your form. Its normal request and hence ur controller responds html

Comment: From the browser, it show the form having data-remote = true.  I had been getting a authenticity token error but that got fixed as well.

Comment: The form_with tag is new in rails 5.1 and by default is ajax.

Comment: An update--- if i remove the other form on the page my ajax works. the other form is not ajax.  I changed that form to ajax but it still interfered.

Comment: The other form was just a normal form_with created by a rails scaffold but is definitely interfering with my ajax request in another form

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to close a div tag. Apparently by not closing a div tag for the form at the top of the page, this form interferes with my ajax form at bottom of page.